# I Have Install this (SUPEE 11086 ) Patch in Magento 1.9.0.4 but Data.php is not working?

Tags: security, patches

I have Install SUPEE 11086 Patch install successfully but not work Properly in backed side? 
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check your Magento server and log files to find out the exact error?

Comment: Have you install that via ssh or manually ?